# What happens when I would leave some breakpoints in my code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, breakpoints

I am making an app for in the app store with objective-c. 
I made a couple of them, but still have the following question.
I use breakpoints a lot to troubleshoot my code, but what happens when I leave one in the code when uploading to Apple.
Will the archive with my project just discard the breakpoint or will the app be uploaded with the breakpoint, but will it not stop the program on an actual device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Breakpoints aren't in the code, as such. They are something that only exists while the app is being debugged. Xcode remembers which breakpoints you had set and re-adds them each time it runs your app in the debugger.

Breakpoints aren't in the archive and won't affect your program on the user's device.